# How to minimize shadow from imageView TVOS Focus CollectionView Swift

Tags: swift, tvos

I have an `UICollectionView` and cells on it. When i focusing on cell, the imageView `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused`. My goal is made this shadow much smaller.

Comment: Did you found a solution yet? Struggling with the same problem ATM

Comment: @Steaphann no, if u will found, write me pls

Comment: @Steaphann just posed an solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my function I don't use `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` I change the size of the image manually :

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        if (self.focused)
        {


                self.imageView.frame.size.width = self.imageView.frame.width+30
                self.imageView.frame.size.height = self.imageView.frame.height+30

                self.imageView.frame.origin.x = self.imageView.frame.origin.x - 15
                self.imageView.frame.origin.y = self.imageView.frame.origin.y - 15


        else
        {

                self.imageView.frame.size.width = self.imageView.frame.width-30
                self.imageView.frame.size.height = self.imageView.frame.height-30

                self.imageView.frame.origin.x = self.imageView.frame.origin.x + 15
                self.imageView.frame.origin.y = self.imageView.frame.origin.y + 15
           }
    }
```

This way you don't have to deal with shadow. Hope this helps